# how to develop PHP and MYSQL ecommerce website without CMS

Tags: php, mysql, magento

i am a magento developer, one of my client want Pure PHP ecommerce website, client dont want any CMS.

i searched on the internet but i didn't get the idea. anybody please give me an idea how to develop ecommerce website using php.

sujjest any tutorials or free demo templates include both frontend and backend with the database

Thanks in advance

Comment: How were they able to make such a clearly informed and illogical decision?

Comment: My client telling like magento or any CMS performance and loading time is    too slow so client decided to go for normal php website. and he wants to sell 70 to 80 products only not more than that

Comment: Nginx, caching, CDN, Ajax loading, minimizing resources (JS, CSS) etc. would improve performance.

Comment: If your client wanted a new car, would they insist on having one designed and built from raw materials? Or would they go to a car salesman and buy one?

Comment: The number of products doesn't matter. In this case Id inform the client how his concerns could be solved (Drakes advice are excellent) and the huge difference in cost. Setting up magento is a rather simple job, assuming the client wants some functionality, admin dashboard with reporting etc, implementing this application is a **huge** job (100x cost?).

Answer (score 3):

Please research the term **CMS**.
Without CMS, your client will not be able to manage the content  (hence the term Content Management System) - so they will not be able to add/remove products, view sales etc. Therefore, I'm not sure your client really knows what they want. You, as a developer, should research it and report to your client.

If you don't want to use Open Source CMS (such as Magento Community Edition) or any CMS after all, you will need to build your own system. To do so, you have to have general **PHP** knowledge (together with Front-end technologies such as HTML/CSS and database, MySQL for example). There are more than plenty tutorials online on all of these aspects.

However, unless you're a PHP expert, it is very unlikely that you will build a better and faster system than those out there (free or commercial). If you are having problems with speeds, make sure you do not overload your site with many custom modules, heavy templates etc., as it is most likely to be caused by the template (loading many images, big js libraries etc.), and not the actual CMS being slow.

My strong advise to you would be to go with one of the **open-source** systems, that have been developed and improved by the community of hundreds of developers.

[Content Management System - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)

Answer (score 0):

You indicated your client has 70 products.  You will need to develop an admin panel to support the CRUD operations for these products, reviews, social, inventory, shipping, returns, payment processing, and any other features you and your client decide are necessary. You could use magento as a checklist for discussion with your client to determine what features they want to support.

For more help with database schema, "Google" - ecommerce database schema to get an idea of what this may look like. Here is a link to a Free downloadable one as an example:
http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Free-eCommerce-MySQL-Database

Decide with your client what payment gateways they want.  Here's a link that poses the various questions that require answers:
http://ecommerce-platforms.com/ecommerce-selling-advice/choose-payment-gateway-ecommerce-store

SSL Certificates are a requirement, and choosing the right one, along with the payment gateway provider is key.  I suggest that you choose a payment gateway product that allows you to process the credit cards, but they keep the transaction data on their side.  Otherwise you are subject to PCI compliance see:
https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/

Lastly, I'll leave you with this link which will give you insight specifically with the building part.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-shopping-cart-with-php-and-mysql--net-5144